# CSS3 radial gradient

Tags: html, css, radial-gradients, css-gradients

I need to know if this is even possible.  The "creative" photoshop department comes up with this image, and before it was just a gradient fading from 1 to 5 colors.  They still do this, but they now how a white circle on top of it.  How would i even go about accomplishing this.  the examples syntax have no exact positioning.  On top of the white circle i need to add specific font and text "in the white"

[image]

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be simpler to go with multiple overlaid gradients as a background.

The first a simple linear gradient, left to right, and a second radial gradient on top.

Then it's just a matter of positioning (absolutely) your text element over the white circle (remember you know where it's positioned)

A quick and dirty demo:

```css
div {
  height: 350px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(circle closest-side at 75% 50%, white, white 60%, transparent), 
    linear-gradient(to right, #344862, white 75%, yellow);
  position: relative;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 75%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor.</span>
</div>
```

**Note**: how the positioning of the radial gradient center is the same as the positioning of the `<span>`. The `transform` just ensures that the text is centered in the circle.

Comment: so there is nothing you can do about the white below and above the circle.

this will be fine, im just saying.  Another issue is what kind of background must you have to understand this.  c++,java, and c# makes me have no clue.

Comment: The left to right gradient was just an example...you can miss out the white in that if you want...you just have to use whatever gradient your PS guys have you. As for background, I'm not sure what you are asking...I did it all with basic HTML/CSS...I'm not sure what the other have to do with the question.

Comment: its just that i can create an entire trading system.  but i cant put a dot in css in a gradient image. makes me think whats more valuable

again thank you for your help

Comment: @Paulie_D I think that he is using *background* as *area of knowledge*, not graphic background

Comment: now this is what i wanted. i had a background div before , fading to 6 colors.  but then they added the white circle and was perplexed as im not a css3 ninja